# Sending a mailable with binary data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to queue a mailable containing a property with a model (`Order`) that has a binary id.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderShipped extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The order instance.
     *
     * @var Order
     */
    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped');
    }
}
```

The `Order` implements the [`Serializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface. In the `serialize`method of the model I'm converting the binary id to a string, so it can be properly encoded to json.

Unfortunately the `serialize`method is never called when I want to queue the mail.

Is this a bug in the framework or am I missing something?

Also I noticed in the PHP docs that, when using the `Serializable`interface, the `__sleep`and `__wakeup`methods are no longer supported:

> Classes that implement this interface no longer support __sleep() and
>   __wakeup().

But the `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` trait seems to override them...

**EDIT**
I'm using [this trait for my binary ids](https://github.com/alsofronie/eloquent-uuid/blob/master/src/UuidBinaryModelTrait.php).
In my `serialize` method I simply call `$this->toArray()`.

Comment: How are you converting binary id to the string?

Comment: post the serialize method code

Comment: @SapneshNaik: I updated the question